# Forcing a program to run in a specific regional mode (in regards to international number formats; i.e. commas and decimal places)

Tags: vb6, internationalization, globalization

I'm a novice at best, so forgive me if this is trivial.  I wrote a piece of software for our American company that is now going to be used internationally.  It's a research tool and relies heavily on mathematical formulas.  We did not take into account the fact that many European countries use decimal points in place of commas and commas in place of decimal points.  This causes the program to crash in many different places.

I've tried switching to the more regional-friendly commands (e.g. CStr instead of Str), but that causes other problems, and becomes a cat-and-mouse game.

Is there some simple work-around where I can force this program to run with the American regional setting?  It seems to be a simple option on the computer itself that can be switched around without rebooting.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the computer's regional settings can be changed, but I don't think there's a way to change those settings for an individual program. The setting is a global one, not a per-app one.

Comment: There isn't any magic bullet that I've ever seen.  You need to be careful about where you do and don't use the various locale-aware and locale-blind conversion functions and avoid implicit coercion like the plague.  Sounds like you have a painful rewrite ahead of you.

Comment: In summary, ALWAYS use numbers/numeric data types internally and ONLY convert to a string for display purposes. This is the only time that the locale comes into play.